# Stopping individual threads

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, parallel-processing

Using the pthread library in C, is it possible to send a SIGSTOP signal to an individual thread?

I want to ensure that even though I create N threads in a loop, all should start executing only when all of them have been created.

I ask because the man page for `pthread_kill()` mentions:

> Signal  dispositions  are 
>   process-wide:  if  a signal handler is
>   installed, the handler will be invoked
>   in the
>          thread *thread*, but **if the disposition of the signal is "stop",
>   "continue", or  "terminate",  this 
>   action  will
>          affect the whole process.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Barriers (see `pthread_barrier_init`) are an even easier way to accomplish what you need.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [mutexes](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/rzahw/rzahwe18rx.htm) and [conditions](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#ConditionVariables) for that.

Here is a [great example](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=/apis/users_78.htm) on how to do just that.